# If a function is uniformly continuous restricted to each line, is it globally uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, examples-counterexamples, uniform-continuity

**Question:** Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that for every line $L$ passing through the origin $(0, 0)$, the restriction of the function $f|_{L} : L\to\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous (we can view $L\cong\mathbb{R}$ if we wish). Does it follow that $f$ is uniformly continuous?

**Motivation.** A friend and I were discussing the following fact: If $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ has bounded partial derivatives, then $f$ is uniformly continuous. One way to prove this fact is to show that $f$ must be Lipschitz, i.e. $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq C |x-y|$ for some constant $C$. My proof for the latter fact uses the following idea: take two points $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, look at the line $L$ joining $x$ and $y$, then restrict $f$ to $L\cong\mathbb{R}$, and use the Mean Value Theorem for the function $f|_{L}$. The derivative of $f|_{L}$ will be bounded, because it is a directional derivative of $f$, which is a linear combination of the partial derivatives of $f$, which are themselves bounded. While formulating this proof, I was naturally lead to ask the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $$f(x,y) = \frac{y}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: Maybe it's just a Monday, but isn't that a uniformly continuous function?

Comment: @ChrisCulter Note that $f(0,y) - f(\delta, y)$ is unbounded for fixed $\delta \ne 0$ but varying $y$.

Comment: Nice answer! A friend of mine suggested another way to see why $f$ is not uniformly continuous. If you restrict $f$ to the set $\{ (x, x^4): x \text{ in } \mathbb{R}\}$, then  $f$ looks like the function $\frac{x^4}{1+x^2}\approx x^2$ which is definitely not uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Let $b:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a bump function supported on $(1,3)$ and let $f(x,y)=b(x)e^y$. Every line through the origin eventually leaves the support of $f$; but $f$ is not uniformly continuous on the line $x=2$.